# Using group_concat With a Condition: Display 0 if Values are Not Equal

Tags: mysql, sql

I just want to display column fields horizontally but also putting a condition to it. Display zero if it has not met the condition.

Example problem: Find the PAYCODE 912 and 686 and display the amount, if not available, display 0

my_table

| EMPLOYEE | PAYCODE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 912 | 1 |
| 1 | 123 | 3 |
| 2 | 912 | 5 |
| 2 | 686 | 7 |
| 3 | 111 | 4 |

Output must be:

| EMPLOYEE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,0 |
| 2 | 5,7 |
| 3 | 0,0 |

My code so far:

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
          IF(PAYCODE = '912', AMOUNT, '0'), 
          IF(PAYCODE = '686', AMOUNT, '0')) 
          SEPARATOR',') as AMOUNT
FROM 
    my_table
```

Note: There are no duplicate paycodes on a similar employee. e.g. two 912 paycodes

Comment: DO you have a table were all paycodes are stored?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes it is from my_table as an example for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking a cross join approach should work here:

```sql
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE,
       GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(t.AMOUNT, 0) ORDER BY e.PAYMENTTYPE DESC) AS AMOUNT
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE FROM my_table) e
CROSS JOIN (SELECT '912' AS PAYMENTTYPE UNION ALL SELECT '686') p
LEFT JOIN my_table t
    ON t.EMPLOYEE = e.EMPLOYEE AND
       t.PAYMENTTYPE = p.PAYMENTTYPE
GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEE;
```

The cross join between the `e` and `p` subqueries generates all employee/payment type combinations of interest (only types 912 and 686).  We then left join to your table to bring in the amounts, which if are missing we report 0 instead.

Comment: Hi tim, thank you for always answering. It took me some time to understand the answer and I think that COALESCE is not working because 0 is not showing when paycode 686 for example is not available.